# Laravel Polymorphic many to many with composite key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, composite-primary-key

I have these models:

#### Invoice:

```php
Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('ref_key')->unique()->primary();
    $table->string('invoice_number')->nullable();
    $table->dateTime('invoice_date')>nullable();
    ...
});
```

#### Invoice_Lines:

```php
Schema::create('invoice_lines', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('line_number');
    $table->string('invoice_ref_key');
    $table->string('nomenclature_key')->nullable();

    ...
    
    $table->primary(['line_number', 'invoice_ref_key']);
    $table->foreign('invoice_ref_key')
          ->references('ref_key')
          ->on('invoices')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

`Invoice_lines` doesn't have own id, and use composite key `['line_number', 'invoice_ref_key']`.

Data for `invoice` and `invoice_lines` comes from another system as one entity:

```php
[
    "ref_key" => "invoice id (uses id from another system, uuid format)",
    "invoice_number" => "...",
    "invoice_date" => "...",
    ...
    "invoice_lines" => [
        [
            'line_number' => 1, 
            'invoice_ref_key' => "invoice id (ref_key)",
            ...
        ],
        [
            'line_number' => 2, 
            'invoice_ref_key' => "invoice id (ref_key)", 
            ...
        ],
        ...
        [
            'line_number' => 15, 
            'invoice_ref_key' => "invoice id (ref_key)", 
            ...
        ],
    ],
]
```

When `invoice` creates or updates this entity explodes on **invoice** and **invoice_lines** models.

Because **invoice_lines** doesn't have own primary key, only composite key, all **invoice_lines** records deletes by `invoice_ref_key` column and recreates from new information.

I need to use `invoice_lines` in polymorphic many to many relationship.

But don't know how deal it with composite key. For example, I have a **Purchase** for **Invoice**, but need `Purchase` only for few **Invoice_line** records.

How I can do it?

In standard `Laravel` many to many polymorphic relationship, I create:

```
Invoice:
  ref_key (id) - uuid,
  ...
```

```
Purchase:
  id - uuid,
  ...
```

```
Purchasables:
  purchase_id - uuid,
  purchasable_id - uuid,
  purchasable_type - string
```

But how use it with models with composite keys?

Or I'm should still use a unique one column key for **invoice_lines**?

## Thanks for any answers!